# The ranking of questions in my "top questions" page

Tags: discussion

When I visit the website, I am directed to a "top questions" page. I would like to know more about how these questions are presented to me.

1. What data is used to generate this ordering?
2. What algorithm/model is being used?
3. Have there been any changes to these previous two things in the past?
4. Are there any planned changes to these two things in the future?

Comment: Do you mean the "Hot Network Questions" along the right side of question pages about midway down?

Comment: @gung no I mean the homepage. The title says "top questions." What makes them the top?

Comment: Huh, I never really noticed that before.

Comment: @gung on mobile it says "All questions" instead

Comment: See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-questions-in-the-hot-tab-selected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This is SE-wide, not just here.  That is, the ideal place for this question would be meta.SE.)

That said, I think the list of questions on the main page is just the display of a [FIFO data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) composed of the questions most recently asked, edited, or answered.  The most recently changed is pushed in to the top, and the 31st / 51st(?) is popped from the bottom.

So far as I know, that has always been the way it worked, and I'm aware of no plans to change it in the future.